# How to create a database backup using H2 and JPA?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am developing a JPA application which uses H2 as the database 
and I want to create a backup while the database is running.
Here is the relevant part of the persistence.xml:

```
  <persistence-unit name="examplePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

This [H2 Tutorial](https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_hibernate) says that I have to use the sql statement "BACKUP TO 'backup.zip'", but I'm not quite sure how.
My attempt so far:

```
entityManager.createQuery("BACKUP TO 'backup.zip'").executeUpdate();
```

But it results in this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: BACKUP near line 1, column 1 [BACKUP TO 'backup.zip']
```

I was hoping, that I don't have to manually export the tables to JSON or CSV. While the export part works, the import is more problematic, since I have a lot of ManyToMany relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `entityManager.createNativeQuery(...)` instead